# Как реализовать диаграммы, изменяемые в реальном времени?

Tags: php, html, jquery

Есть изменяемая статистика, хранящаяся в бд. Хочется сделать красивое отображение статистики с помощью графиков/диаграмм, притом диаграммы будут различные по внешнему виду. Сразу пришла идея перерисовки графика каждую секунду с помощью `.empty()` и `.removedata()`. Все ничего, но на мобильных версиях заметно очень этот процесс (мерцание), а хотелось бы непрерывное изменение данных на диаграммах.
Вопроса по сути два:

1. Какие технологии (точнее какой принцип)  лучше использовать для задачи обновления диаграмм в реалтайме без перерисовки и обновления страницы.
2. Какими инструментами пользоваться для рисования диаграмм и графиков, с учётом того, что, возможно, придётся выполнять их со специфическим внешним видом (круговые, плоские, овальные, полосы разного цвета и размера, а может и изменяемые картинки вместо них и тд). Тут возможно самому рисовать с помощью canvas?

Comment: Все популярные библиотеки отрисовки графиков умеют делать то, что вы хотите и уже оптимизированы. Вы смотрели какие-то из них? Почему они вам не подошли?

Comment: Руками диаграмы можно порисовать спомощью http://www.highcharts.com/

Вообще рекомендую посмотреть в специализированные дашбоарды типо http://grafana.org/ или https://influxdata.com/time-series-platform/chronograf/

Comment: Попробуй создавать диаграммы, с помощью этой библиотеки https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/

Comment: Пробовал circliful, и ещё несколько простых скриптов. Большие библиотеки использовать пока не решился из-за нецелесообразности если для оборачивания их в свой дизайн придётся использовать костыли, и решение будет, в основном, использоваться в мобильных версиях ос. Хотелось бы кастомизировать диаграммы  для дальнейшего их дизайна. Поэтому чтобы не изобретать велосипед и обратился за помощью) Если же пойму, что нет нужного решения хочу понять принцип работы по рисованию графиков и обновлению их в реалтайме)

Comment: Спасибо комментирующим, буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

не хватает кармы для комментария, извините )
для получения данных с сервера в режиме realtime рекомендую изучить [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) базового уровня хватит с головой, необходимые модули: [socket.io](https://socket.io/) и модуль бд, к примеру [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)

Comment: что касается визуализации: [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) (мощный но сложный фреймворк), если попроще - [dygraph](http://dygraphs.com/)